# How to use input mapping context in UE5 (without blueprint)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am a beginner in UE5 (I started learning yesterday), and I am now working on a simple task. It takes the WSAD and mouse to do simple movement and camera operations using input mapping context.

However, after my self-learning, I end up with this:

```
UCLASS()
class ASSIGNMENT1_API AFirstPersonCharactor : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AFirstPersonCharactor();
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components|Camera")
    UCameraComponent* camera;


    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Input|Actions")
    UInputAction *IA_KB_CM_InOut;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Input|Actions")
    UInputAction* IA_KB_CM_LeftRight;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Input|Actions")
    UInputAction* IA_KB_CL_UpDown;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Input|Actions")
    UInputAction* IA_KB_CL_LeftRight;



    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Input|Actions")
    TSoftObjectPtr<UInputMappingContext> IMCControls;

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    void KB_CM_InOut(const FInputActionInstance& Instance);

    void KB_CM_LeftRight(const FInputActionInstance& Instance);

    void KB_CL_UpDown(const FInputActionInstance& Instance);

    void KB_CL_LeftRight(const FInputActionInstance& Instance);

};
```

and this is my cpp file:

```
// Sets default values
AFirstPersonCharactor::AFirstPersonCharactor()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("FirstPersonCamera"));
    camera->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
    camera->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0));

}

void AFirstPersonCharactor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
}

// Called every frame
void AFirstPersonCharactor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AFirstPersonCharactor::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
    if (ULocalPlayer* LocalPlayer = Cast<ULocalPlayer>(GetController()))
    {   
        
        if (UEnhancedInputLocalPlayerSubsystem* InputSystem = LocalPlayer->GetSubsystem<UEnhancedInputLocalPlayerSubsystem>())
        {
            InputSystem->AddMappingContext(IMCControls.LoadSynchronous(),10);
        }
    }
    
    UEnhancedInputComponent* input = Cast<UEnhancedInputComponent>(PlayerInputComponent);

    if (IA_KB_CM_InOut) {
        input->BindAction(IA_KB_CM_InOut, ETriggerEvent::Started, this, &AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CM_InOut);
    }
    if (IA_KB_CM_LeftRight) {
        input->BindAction(IA_KB_CM_LeftRight, ETriggerEvent::Started, this, &AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CM_LeftRight);
    }
    if (IA_KB_CL_UpDown) {
        input->BindAction(IA_KB_CL_UpDown, ETriggerEvent::Started, this, &AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CL_UpDown);
    }
    if (IA_KB_CL_LeftRight) {
        input->BindAction(IA_KB_CL_LeftRight, ETriggerEvent::Started, this, &AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CL_LeftRight);
    }
}

void AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CM_InOut(const FInputActionInstance &Instance)
{
    printf("a");
    float FloatValue = Instance.GetValue().Get<float>();
    if (FloatValue != 0) {
        AddMovementInput(GetActorForwardVector(),FloatValue);
    }
}

void AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CM_LeftRight(const FInputActionInstance& Instance)
{
    float FloatValue = Instance.GetValue().Get<float>();
    if (FloatValue != 0) {
        AddMovementInput(GetActorRightVector(), FloatValue);
    }

}

void AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CL_LeftRight(const FInputActionInstance& Instance)
{
    float FloatValue = Instance.GetValue().Get<float>();
    if (FloatValue != 0) {
        AddControllerYawInput(FloatValue);
    }
}

void AFirstPersonCharactor::KB_CL_UpDown(const FInputActionInstance& Instance)
{
    float FloatValue = Instance.GetValue().Get<float>();
    if (FloatValue != 0) {
        AddControllerPitchInput(FloatValue);
    }
}
```

This ends with no bug, and I have the `inputAction` and `inputMappingContext` assets set in the outliner. But no matter which key I press, there are always no behaviours I can observe.

EDIT: after I add `GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT("haha"));` to debug, I found that my `SetupPlayerInputComponent` is working, but

```
if (ULocalPlayer* LocalPlayer = Cast<ULocalPlayer>(GetController()))
```

probably not.

Comment: Just to clarify: You have used an attached debugger during a PIE-Session and verified that "SetupPlayerInputComponent" runs properly and everything is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to cast your controller to local player, and also you'd rather setup `MappingContext` in `BeginPlay()` rather than in `SetupInputComponent(...)`.
So instead of doing that cast and then trying to add mapping context do this:

```
if (auto PlayerController = Cast<APlayerController>(Controller))
{
    if (UEnhancedInputLocalPlayerSubsystem* Subsystem = ULocalPlayer::GetSubsystem<UEnhancedInputLocalPlayerSubsystem>(PlayerController->GetLocalPlayer()))
    {
        Subsystem->AddMappingContext(DefaultMappingContext, 0);
    }
}
```